# Django How to pass list of values one views function to other views function

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I want pass list of values from with in the views with `HttpResponseRedirect`. I don't want session variables. How can I do this functions are as follows.

```
def fun_one(request):
        x = [a,b,c,d]
    y = [1,2,3,4]
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/fun_two/')
def fun_two(request):
    .
    .
    .
    print "i want use function One values x & y here"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you Must use `HttpResponseRedirect`, one way would be to pass the values as GET parameters -

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/fun_two/?y=1,2,3,4')
```

And reading them back with `request.GET.get('y')` and then just `split(',')`.

Comment: Thank You Bibhas, Please let me know how can I Pass dynamic Object values like  y = UserLogin.objects.all()

Comment: I won't prefer doing so. There is no reason to do it either

Comment: Why not just fetch the records in the second view?

Comment: Explain me some more detailed with any example how can fetchfetch the records in second view..?

Comment: Your example doesnt even have the query in the first view. Explain your problem better.

Comment: Problem is just I want to pass dynamic object values from one view function to HttpResponseRedirect view function(Redirected view function).

Comment: Dynamic values of course can be generated in another view too.
In your `fun_two` view why don't you do?
`your_value = UserLogin.objects.all()`